# Close all child activities down to parent activity

Tags: android, android-activity

If i have the following

Parent activity > activity 1 > activity 2 > activity 3

Pressing the back button will go back to:
Parent activity > activity 1 > activity 2

Pressing again will go to:
Parent activity > activity 1

is there any way that I can programatically finish activity 1,2 and 3 from activity 3 itself.

In IOS there is a function called popToRootViewControllerAnimated, Which is the type of concept I require in Android

thanks

Comment: Do you need those activities open when you go to the next? Is there a reason you don't call `finish()` on each when you leave and go to the next?

Comment: Yes i need them all. I need to be able to traverse backwards normally using the back button AND have a home button on activity 3 which jumps directly back to the parent activity, in case the user wants to jump home in one click.

Comment: I understand that but in that case you just override `onBackPressed` to create whichever activity with an `intent`. If they click your home button then you simply create the parent activity.

Answer (score 1):

Launch the child Activities with `startActivityForResult()` and then in `onActivityResult()` call `finish()`. This will bring you back to the Parent Activity.

Alternatively you can also use the Intent flag [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) while calling `startActivity()` on Parent Activity from Activity 3.

Comment: Thanks for this, decided to try this flag whilst starting the activity.

Comment: Here's what I did. I created a new intent of "parent activity", then set the method .SetFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP).

Then I started a new activity with this intent from activity 3.

This caused activity 2 and 3 to finish and parent activity to become the root activity - as required.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Please click the checkmark in this answer to accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add Flag  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP  while you call startActivity from your last activity. It will clear the activity stack

Answer (score 0):

Check in onResume() of activity2 if you came from activity3 and call finish(), if yes. Same for activity1.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this algorithm can be usefull;

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch(keyCode)
    {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            //here you'll check if activity3 alive then join
            //else if activity2 alive then join
            //else if activity1 alive then join
            //else finish(); 
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```